# C++ return statement comes back empty

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

consider this arduino code:

```
class Sensor{
  public:
  Sensor();
  Sensor(const char* name, int pin, float multiplier);
  int get_value();
  const char get_name();
  private:
  int readinput();
  int _pin;
  int _output;
  const char* _name;
  int _input;
  float _multiplier;
  };

Sensor::Sensor(){
  }
Sensor::Sensor(const char* name, int pin, float multiplier){
  _pin = pin;
  _multiplier = multiplier;
  _name = name;
  pinMode(_pin, INPUT);
  }

int Sensor::readinput(){
  return analogRead(_pin);
  }

int Sensor::get_value(){
  _input = readinput();
  _output = _input * _multiplier;
  return _output;
  }

const char Sensor::get_name(){
  return _name;
  }
```

When I create an array of this class with data from a JSON file, interpreted with arduinoJson, and I try to return the name of a certain sensor in the array this way:

```
_sensors[i].get_name());
```

it comes back empty!

I have been searching the internet for hours now and I think it might have something to do with the fact that the arduinoJson library returns all of its text values as a const char*.

The problem is, I just can't seem to figure out how the combination of pointers and constants work, especially if the input for the parameter is another pointer!

EDIT: Here is how I construct the array.

```
class Communicator{
  public:
  Communicator();
  int checker();
  void sensorinitiater();
  private:
  Sensor _sensors[];
  int _arraysize;
  };

Communicator::Communicator(){
  }

int Communicator::checker(){
  while(true) {
    if(Serial.readString() == "give sensor values") {
     StaticJsonBuffer<600> jsonBuffer;
     JsonObject& sensorvalues = jsonBuffer.createObject();
     for(int i = 0; i < _arraysize; i++){
        Serial.println("gathering sensor data");
        Serial.flush();
        sensorvalues[_sensors[i].get_name()] = _sensors[i].get_value();
      }

     };
    }
  }

void Communicator::sensorinitiater(){ //check if JSON file with sensor data comes in, initiate sensors
  bool checker = true;
  StaticJsonBuffer<600> jsonBuffer;
  while(checker) {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {

    checker = false;
    String sensorjson = Serial.readString();
    JsonObject& sensorprop = jsonBuffer.parseObject(sensorjson);
    if(!sensorprop.success()){
      Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
      Serial.flush();
      Serial.println(sensorjson);
      Serial.flush();
      sensorinitiater();  
      };
    Serial.println("parseObject() succeeded");
    Serial.flush();
    _arraysize = sensorprop.size();
    Serial.println(_arraysize);
    Sensor _sensors[_arraysize];
    for (JsonObject::iterator it=sensorprop.begin(); it!=sensorprop.end(); ++it){
      int i = 0;

      Sensor(sensorprop[it->key]["name"], sensorprop[it->key]["pin"], sensorprop[it->key]["linear_coefficient"]); _sensors[i];

      Serial.println(_sensors[i].get_name());
      Serial.flush();
      i++;

      }

    }
  }
 Serial.flush();
 Serial.println("finalising sensors");
}
  Communicator com;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  com.sensorinitiater();
  com.checker();
}
```

as soon as the arduino detects an input(the JSON file) it reserves the memory space and parses the JSOn string.

I then iterate over the file to create a sensor for every object in the JSON file.

I use a lot of

```
Serial.flush()
```

to make sure the serial monitor doesn't get overloaded.

Comment: Please show us how you're constructing the `Sensor`. You may have more than one error. (What *precisely* are you saving a pointer to? Who allocated it? Who ensures it stays valid? Who is responsible for freeing it? If you can't answer these questions, you're expecting your code to work by magic.)

Comment: I edited the code to show how I make the objects.

Answer (score 1):

The function should return a pointer like this:

```
const char* Sensor::get_name()
```

Comment: now it returns my entire json file completely out of order.

Comment: Likely because you are saving a pointer to memory that you do not own. See my comment to the question.